# datatable with list and reverse to datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a C# Windows Forms application and I have a data table; I need to perform a specific task on one column for this purpose I use the following query. The problem is that the final result is in another variable which name is solution1 and solution2.

Is there any way to get same output on my existing table on tag section and print Sno in tag section against qualified numbers, these number should be duplicate but sno is unique

This is my table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbTIL.png)

```
string[] A = dm.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>(dm.Columns[2])).ToArray();
```

and then

```
double[] arrDouble = new double[A.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    arrDouble[i] = double.Parse(A[i]);
}
  
List<Tuple<string, double>> list = new List<Tuple<string, double>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<string, double>(arrDouble[0].ToString(), arrDouble[0]));

for (int i = 1; i < arrDouble.Length; i++)
{
    var newlist = new List<Tuple<string, double>>();
    list.ForEach(l => newlist.Add(new Tuple<string, double>(l.Item1 + " " + arrDouble[i], l.Item2 + arrDouble[i])));
    list.Add(new Tuple<string, double>(arrDouble[i].ToString(), arrDouble[i]));
    list.AddRange(newlist);
}

double sumN = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < arrDouble.Length; j++)
{
    sumN += arrDouble[j];
}
  
Tuple<string, double> solution2;

if (sumN > targetN)
{
    Tuple<string, double> solution = list.Where(l => l.Item2 >= targetN).OrderBy(o => o.Item2).First();
    solution2 = solution;
}
else
{
    Tuple<string, double> solution = list.Where(l => l.Item2 >= sumN).OrderBy(o => o.Item2).Last();
    solution2 = solution;
}
  
double lowest_weight = 0;
Tuple<string, double> solution1;
lowest_weight = list.Min(c => c.Item2);

if (targetN > lowest_weight)
{
    Tuple<string, double> solution3 = list.Where(l => l.Item2 <= targetN).OrderBy(o => o.Item2).Last();
    solution1 = solution3;
}
else
{
    //Tuple<string, double> solution3 = new Tuple<string,double>("0",0);
    Tuple<string, double> solution3 = list.Where(l => l.Item2 >= targetN).OrderBy(o => o.Item2).First();
    solution1 = solution3;
}
  
//Console.WriteLine(solution);
//Console.WriteLine(solution1);
//if  solution is nearest to target
if (Math.Abs(solution2.Item2 - targetN) < Math.Abs(solution1.Item2 - targetN))
{
    Console.WriteLine(solution2);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(solution1);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Rather than us having to work out what that code does, why don't you explain it in words.. i.e. You want the tag to be what.. the [Sno] concat the min([weight])?

Comment: This code select the combination of numbers from the table and give best result which is near to target number.

Comment: What does "best result near to target number" mean? Your table image has lots of numbers; what does "number" mean?

Comment: Sum of all the weights most nearest to target or equal to target if find multiple solution which make exact to target or most near and there sum are same than pick any one of them.

Comment: I don't really understand the algorithm as presented in the comment, can you put sum numbers to it? "sum of most nearest" - sum implies there are more than one, most nearest sort of makes sense but what does *near* mean?... Answer by editing the question please, not in a comment